# How to change text to voice engine in android from english to urdu?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am working on project in which I need voice into urdu. So any one can tell me how I can change this voice?
Thanks

```
public void onInit(int status) {
xy.setPitch(1);
if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    xy.speak("this is text to speech in engish" +
            "           ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either:

```
tts.setLanguage(new Locale("ur"));
```

Or:

```
tts.setLanguage(new Locale("urd"));
```

Used this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) to find out.

Comment: thanks for reply. Does urdu engine is available in google TTS?

Comment: After implementation and running its still in English?

Comment: the entire class if its small, or just everywhere you reference text to speech...

Comment: @Rana did you find any method to make this URDU TTS work? please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

there are two option to do that.
1- goto androd setting and change your language to URDU
2- tts.setLanguage(new Local("urd"));

Answer (score 0):

t1=new TextToSpeech ( getApplicationContext (), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener () {
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

```
                t1.setLanguage(new Locale("ur"));
            }**strong text**
```

Comment: In order to provide better and useful answer, please format the code properly and do not copy/paste code without detailed explanation of what exactly the does. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969143/17974122